# What is the best way for implementing customer phones, shipping details and order?

Tags: database-design

I need to store multiple phones and shipping details for customer. Also, when customer makes and order he will have an ability to choose from his entered phones/shipping details.

For example, Customer 1 can have 3 phones and 5 shipping details. During order he should choose one phone and one shipping place.

From another side, I think that most people will have one phone and one shipping place.

Now, I have two approaches.

1. Table Users
   Table Address
   Table UserAddress (many-to-many from User and Address)
   Table Phones
   Table UserPhones (many-to-many from User and Phones)
   Table Order - two fields: phone and address, which are populated (as strings) from appropriate tables.

   Disadvantage is that strings are stored, instead of references. So, inefficient usage of space.
2. Table Users
   Table Address
   Table UserAddress (many-to-many from User and Address)
   Table Phones
   Table UserPhones (many-to-many from User and Phones)
   Table UserInfo (many-to-many from UserAddress and UserPhone)
   Table Order - one field: reference to UserInfo

   Disadvantage is user id is in both tables UserAddress and UserPhones.

What is the best way to implement such design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first approach but just change `Order` to have a `UserPhoneID` and a `UserAddressID` (foreign keys linking to primary keys `ID` in `UserPhone` and `ID` in `UserAddress` respectively).

This requires that, as soon as an order is placed, that the `UserPhone` entry be created, and that a user may only deliver to an address linked to their account, but this makes sense.

Since a phone (presumably) can't belong to multiple users, you might want to scrap `UserPhone` altogether and just put a `UserID` field in `Phone`.

Similarly it might make sense to scrap `UserAddress`, although there are two advantages to keeping it:

- You don't need to repeat all the data for users living at the same address.
  This is a trade-off between repeating the address for those living at the same address and using more space than required for those who are the only user living at some address. The best option would really depend on the data.
- It's easy to link users using the same address, which may be useful for statistical purposes, among others.

> Disadvantage is user id is in both tables UserAddress and UserPhones.

This isn't really a disadvantage.

If users can have multiple phones or addresses, this is the best way to model this.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate?

- Table Users
- Table UserAddresses (references Users)
- Table UserPhones (references Users)
- Table Orders (references Users, UserAddresses and UserPhones)

Comment: Thought about it. Not very elegant, because we actually store userid three times.

Comment: Well, that's how you implement reference in relational database. This is not redundancy.

Comment: Thanks. I think thiis the best option.